# Struts 1 - How to pick up a table row values to process in another JSP page

Tags: html-table, struts

I'm facing this trouble: I have a `<table>` filled (`<logic:iterate>`) with some data coming from an Action, the last value (of each table row) is a link that would drives me to another JSP page with the data of the row where the link was clicked to edit the corresponding values.

The fact is that I don't have any idea how to grab the values from that row and pass they to the other JSP page once the link is clicked.

Any ideas / example / implementation?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that creates the link (in your table rendering JSP) can embed the ID of the object for that row in the link as query parameter such as `?objectId=13AB73C`. (For security reasons it's even better to embed a unique hash of the ID rather than an actual database id). That id can then be obtained from the request parameters.

Once you have the id of the object for the row, you can load the data from the database for your editing page.

Comment: Yeap, maybe it would be a solution. It is what I do in ASP.NET WebForms, but I'm very new to Struts; the fact is that I don't know how to grab that value from the JSP and call an Action (for instance)...I mean, how to pass this value to the action that will be called once the link is clicked.

Comment: When you click a link (if it's really a link, i.e. <a href="">) then the browser issues a whole new web request. That request will be subject to your struts-config action mappings just like any other request, including the one for the page that drew the table. The URL in the href effectively determines the action. The action then uses the parameter to do it's thing. The same thing holds true if you are doing ajax requests into a struts system, the only difference is your result jsp produces JSON, not html. Disclaimer: I have not used struts since struts 1.x, some terminology may differ a bit.